# How to convert readable date time in timestamp which comes from backend

Tags: angularjs, date, time

I want to convert the commit date and time to time stamp which I  get from my APIs.

But I don't know how to do this in angular?
Here is my controller code :

```
var commitDate = item.commitMetaData.commitDate;
        var dat = new Date(commitDate);
```

But it says "Invalid Date"

PS: Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello, I use moment to manipulate dates in my angular apps. You can try to use [moment](https://momentjs.com).

Comment: log to  console and check what you are getting in `commitDate`

Comment: Any Example for that will be appreciable

Comment: I got :
{monthValue: 10, year: 2017, month: "OCTOBER", dayOfMonth: 10, dayOfWeek: "TUESDAY", …}
chronology
:
{calendarType: "iso8601", id: "ISO"}
dayOfMonth
:
10
dayOfWeek
:
"TUESDAY"
dayOfYear
:
283
hour
:
19
minute
:
5
month
:
"OCTOBER"
monthValue
:
10
nano
:
748000000
second
:
1
year
:
2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is generate the date from the values `montValue` , `year`, `dayOfMonth`

with plain Javascript you could just do

```
var d = new Date();
d.setMonth(commitDate.monthValue +1);  //see explanation below
d.setDate(commitDate.dayOfMonth);
d.setYear(commitDate.year);
```

be careful the months start at 0 so January is actually 0 so in your example you would have to add  +1

You can also create a filter for this

```
.filter('createDate', function ($filter) {
    return function (input) {
        if (input != null && input != undefined) {
            var d = new Date();
            d.setMonth(input.monthValue +1);  //see explanation below
            d.setDate(input.dayOfMonth);
            d.setYear(input.year);
            return d;
        } 

    };
})
```

and call it like

```
var commitDate = item.commitMetaData.commitDate;
var dat = $filter('createDate')(commitDate);
```

reference [JS Date](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)